# Чем визуализировать траекторию по точкам?

Tags: delphi, 3d, график

Есть куча точек с координатами (X,Y,Z), которые образуют траекторию в пространстве.
В чём и как мне построить, и какой компонент в Delphi мне надо использовать?

Comment: использовать пространственную кривую безье например

Comment: Какая версия Делфи? Выбираете FMX или VCL ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Из платных компонентов - TChart Pro, в нем есть Series.AddXYZ
2. Из бесплатных - например, [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/) , ключевые слова mesh, poligon. Впрочем, по ссылке, кроме библиотеки, еще и масса примеров.